# Mysql syntax error in select statement

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have a table `main_tag` with structure as

```
1   id int(100) 
2   name varchar(100)   
3   description varchar(1000)
4   added_on timestamp
```

and have function of php that is as follows

```
function all_data_of_main_tag_table(){

        include_once 'db.php';
        $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        $json = array();
        $nameQuery ='SELECT * FROM `main_tag` WHERE 1';
        echo '<br>'.$nameQuery.'<br>';
        $rsnameQuery = $conn->query($nameQuery);      
        if($rsnameQuery === false){
            echo 'hi'.'<br>';
            trigger_error('Wrong SQL: '.$nameQuery.' Error: '.$conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        else{
           $rows_returned = $rsnameQuery->num_rows;
        }
        while($row = $rsnameQuery->fetch_assoc()){
            $json =$row;
        }
        $conn->close();
        return $json;
    }
```

On running this function it is giving error:

```
{
  "description": null,
  "name": null,
  "id": null
}
MySQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Comment: have you tried query as: SELECT * FROM main_tag

Comment: your query seems alright.

Comment: WHERE 1=1 try this

Comment: Where's the "wrong SQL" bit gone? Perhaps this error message refers to a different query

Comment: Are you sure that's the query that gets the error? The error message in your code begins with `Wrong SQL:`, but your message says `MySQL error:`. It also doesn't print `$nameQuery` like your `trigger_error()` call does.

Comment: Also, if you want to push onto an array, you should use `$json[] = $row;`. You're overwriting the variable each time, so you only get the last row.

Answer (score 2):

In your query, you didn't specify where to look

```
Where 1
```

It does not specify any column

```
// it should be something like this 
Where id = 1
```

So your query be like this

```
$nameQuery ='SELECT * FROM `main_tag` WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

my bad my query was ok the error was of other query. however

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsnameQuery)) {
   $json[] = $row;
}
```

this was to be written instead of

```
while($row = $rsnameQuery->fetch_assoc()){
     $json =$row;
}
```

This was not returning the data.